# Removing index from returned data

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data-frame (`df`)

which looks like:

```
  first_name surname location identifier
0       Fred   Smith   London  FredSmith
1       Jane   Jones  Bristol  JaneJones
```

I am trying to query a particular field and return it to a variable `value` using:

```
value = df.loc[df['identifier'] == query_identifier ,'location']
```

so where `query_identifier` is equal to `FredSmith` I get returned to `value`:

```
0 London
```

How can I remove the `0` so I just have:

```
London
```

Comment: I encounter this all the time. The result is a series of length 1. To get the value, try `value.iloc[0]` or `value.values[0]`.

Comment: @IanS Yes you are right. I guess then the OP should use only values and process with loop. I will edit that method in my answer too.

Comment: you can also use: `df.loc[df['identifier'] == 'FredSmith','location'].iat[0]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this statement:

```
value = df.loc[df['identifier'] == "FredSmith" ,'location'].values[0]
```

This will help you.

If there is multiple values for the same identifier, then:

```
value = df.loc[df['identifier'] == "FredSmith" ,'location'].values
for df_values in value:  
    print(df_values)
```

This is just enhancement.